# How to add ISO 9 Latin char in the rune

Tags: go, unicode, encoding

I want to replace accent characters before encoding transform. To avoid `illegal rune literal`, I'm using Unicode. But that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to put this kind of accent chars in rune?

```
func replaceAccents(s string) string {
    // Replace accent characters
    b := bytes.NewBufferString("")
    for _, c := range s {
        // Check transliterations first
        if val, ok := transliterations[c]; ok {
            b.WriteString(val)
        } else {
            b.WriteRune(c)
        }
    }
    return b.String()
}
var transliterations = map[rune]string{
    'D' + 0x0302:    "D", // D̂ is an illegal rune literal
    0x004A + 0x030C: "J",
    0x004C + 0x0302: "L",
    0x004D + 0x0302: "M",
    0x004E + 0x0302: "N",
    0x0064 + 0x0302: "D",
    0x006C + 0x0302: "L",
    0x006D + 0x0302: "M",
    0x006E + 0x0302: "N",
}
```

The native solution will be a normalizer, but I'm still wondering how to add these special characters in rune.

```
normalizer := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, runes.Remove(runes.In(unicode.Mn)), norm.NFC)
s, _, _ = transform.String(normalizer, s)
```

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/normalization

Comment: Yeah, that solves but I'm curious how to present it in rune.

Comment: You can’t put two codepoints in one rune.

Comment: @Festum I assume that there is no single-codepoint D̂ in unicode. At least I could not find one with a quick glance. So you need to resort to do the glyph + combining accent, which (as Biffen writes) you can't put into one rune.

Comment: Thanks! @topskip now I know the proper way to handle it.

Comment: And: I doubt that `0x004A + 0x030C: "J",` and the other lines are doing what you want. You get 854 (and other numbers) which is a totally different code point.